# Fragments showing white screen when navigating to next page in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

When I try to move from the Home_Fragment screen to the Second Fragment screen I get a white background screen and then when I try to go from Second Fragment to Home_Fragment again I get a white background in my app. Please guide me why I am facing this kind of problems here I upload my tried code.

**load Home Fragment Code**

```
 private void loadHomeFragment() {
    selectNavMenu();
    setToolbarTitle();
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }
    Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            homeFragmentCalled();
        }
    };
    if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
        mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
    }
    drawer.closeDrawers();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

**Navigation View**

```
 private void setUpNavigationView() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_TIMETABLE;
                    homeFragmentCalled();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_performance:
                    navItemIndex = 1;
                    CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PERFORMANCE;
                    secondFragmentCalled();
                    break;

                default:
                    navItemIndex = 0;
            }
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
            }
            menuItem.setChecked(true);

            loadHomeFragment();

            return true;
        }
    });

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

**Calling Fragment Method to Navigate**

```
public void homeFragmentCalled() {
    Log.d("MainActivity ", "homeFragmentCalled called ");
    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, homeFragment, "homeFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public void secondFragmentCalled() {
    performanceFragment = new PerformanceFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, performanceFragment, "performanceFragment");
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

I Google and found lot of questions. I followed many answer but same error  here are code that I used

`replace` `'add`

Changed background colour of fragment and also did

`fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);`

Sorry for my English also thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell what is in PerformanceFragment and PerformanceFragment?

Comment: try removing `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` ?

Comment: in  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null) instead of passing null pass unique value every time when replacing fragment. and once check your Home and PerformanceFragment in both view is getting inflated or not, i thing this two may be the issue. please share you both fragment code.

Comment: I try removing this line ==>  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);  , But same issue.

Comment: public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public HomeFragment() {
    }
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testing, container, false);
     return rootView;
    }  }

Comment: @LovekushVishwakarma

Answer (score 1):

If your fragment or activity contains itself async tasks and when you write your UI code into this tasks ( I mean you are using your UI code not in UI thread ) , you need use extra methods.

Just put your UI codes inside this:

```
runOnUiThread {
   // enter code here
}
```

If you are using fragments:

```
activity?.runOnUiThread {
   // enter code here
}
```